# mediarecoder start failed -19 using libstreaming android with sony z series

Tags: android, h.264, rtsp, live-streaming

I'm getting an error when I start a live streaming using mediarecoder using ***libstreaming android*** on sony z and wowza streaming server.

> 07-20 10:49:37.832: E/MediaRecorder(6752): start failed: -19
>   ConfNotSupportedException

This error is thrown when I change frame rate of video in (15 < fps < 30 or fps > 30). If I set fps = 15 or fps = 30, this error is not thrown. This error is only on sony z device, on some different devices are Samsung, Htc, Nexus are not.

I downloaded Wowza Gocoder app to test whether this error is only on sony z. And, I can change fps from 15 to 60 without any errors. So, I guess the ***libstreaming*** library has problems.

My config code :

```
// Configures the SessionBuilder
mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
        .setContext(getApplicationContext())
        .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
        .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
        .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
        .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView).setPreviewOrientation(0)
        .setCallback(this).build();

// Configures the RTSP client
mClient = new RtspClient();
mClient.setSession(mSession);
mClient.setCallback(this);

// Use this to force streaming with the MediaRecorder API
mSession.getVideoTrack().setStreamingMethod(
        MediaStream.MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API);
```

This code below start stream :

```
    protected void encodeWithMediaRecorder() throws IOException, ConfNotSupportedException {

        Log.d(TAG,"Video encoded using the MediaRecorder API");

        // We need a local socket to forward data output by the camera to the packetizer
        createSockets();

        // Reopens the camera if needed
        destroyCamera();
        createCamera();

        // The camera must be unlocked before the MediaRecorder can use it
        unlockCamera();

        try {
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(mVideoEncoder);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mRequestedQuality.resX,mRequestedQuality.resY);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mRequestedQuality.framerate);

            // The bandwidth actually consumed is often above what was requested 
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate((int)(mRequestedQuality.bitrate*0.8));

            // We write the output of the camera in a local socket instead of a file !          
            // This one little trick makes streaming feasible quiet simply: data from the camera
            // can then be manipulated at the other end of the socket
            FileDescriptor fd = null;
            if (sPipeApi == PIPE_API_PFD) {
                fd = mParcelWrite.getFileDescriptor();
            } else  {
                fd = mSender.getFileDescriptor();
            }
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fd);

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConfNotSupportedException(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**Any one have ideas?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mRequestedQuality.framerate);
```

solved my problem.